# Is it possible to customise the prompt to show the if there are any background jobs?

Tags: bash, prompt, background-process, jobs

Is it possible to customise the bash prompt to show the if there are any background jobs?  I find it easy to forget that there are background jobs.

Say if the prompt was...

```
$
```

Is there a way to make it show the number of background jobs?  For example, if there were two background jobs sent to the background using `CTRL+Z`, the prompt would be...

```
2 $
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put `\j` in your prompt.  From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html#Printing-a-Prompt):

> `\j`
>      The number of jobs currently managed by the shell

---

<sup>Just remember that prompts do go stale and jobs can finish at any time, so if you have left the terminal idle, you'll want to redisplay the prompt.</sup>

---

At the cost of requiring an extra process just to print your prompt, you can make the `\j` only appear if any jobs exist.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='hasjobs=$(jobs -p)'
PS1='${hasjobs:+\j }\$ '
```

Comment: I want to make it so that it only shows this when there are background jobs, and have the usual prompt when there aren't any.  What could I have it check for, so that I can use `if` and `else` (or is there a better way)?  Thanks.

Comment: @paradroid Sorry, I don't know of any non-ugly way to do that.  Are you really sure that is necessary?

Comment: Well, I'd like to do it, as long as it works fast enough.

Comment: @paradroid I edited the answer to add a semi-ugly hack.  As far as speed, the performance hit will be negligible on most modern systems.

Comment: Sorry, not a clairvoyant -- you'll have to be more specific about your unexpected results and what you did to get them.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh, you can use `%j` to indicate the number of jobs and `"%1(j.%j.)"` to show the number of jobs if there is at least one running and otherwise show nothing (instead of 0). Eg. `RPROMPT="%1(j.%j.)"` to show it in the prompt on the right hand side. [More info in the manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815652/unable-to-put-x-to-right-prompt-to-indicate-number-of-jobs-in-zsh).