# Show jobs count only if it is more than 0

Tags: bash

I have a `jobscount()` function:

```
jobscount() {
   local stopped='$(jobs -s | wc -l | tr -d " ")'
   local running='$(jobs -r | wc -l | tr -d " ")'
   echo -n "${running}r/${stopped}s"
}
```

I use this function in my `$PS1`:

```
PS1=" \w $(jobscount) \$ "
```

The only problem is if there is no background process running or there is no stopped jobs, this function uselessly occupies `$PS1` space. What I want is if either of the `stopped` or `running` value is more than `0`, **only then** it shows up.

Comment: [Related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35728/9537).

Comment: Is the `tr -d ' '` necessary?

Comment: @jw013 It was for me, perhaps gnu `wc` is different, but on OS X each output column is separated by 7 spaces - including before the first.

Comment: Another [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646917/show-job-count-in-bash-prompt-only-if-nonzero), on SO.

Answer (score 7):

You guys are making this way too complicated. Just check if the output from `jobs` is non-empty and then add `\j` to your PS1 string.

```
if [ -n "$(jobs -p)" ]; then echo "\j"; fi
```

Here's a snippet from my prompt:

```
#Show number of jobs if at least one job
export PS1+='`if [ -n "$(jobs -p)" ]; then echo "(\j)"; fi`'
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I suggest to fix your quoting. You current function does not output useful data when run stand-alone from the command prompt.

Then add a condition, using the [OR list separator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists), before the `echo`:

```
jobscount() {
  local stopped=$(jobs -sp | wc -l)
  local running=$(jobs -rp | wc -l)
  ((running+stopped)) && echo -n "${running}r/${stopped}s "
}

PS1=' \w $(jobscount)\$ '
```

I also suggest to add `-p` to the `jobs` calls so they output only process PIDs. Otherwise a `yes $'foo\nbar' &` command, listed on 2 lines, would be counted twice.

Comment: Here is what happens. 1. When I remove the quotes around them, the function **don't work** (there is always *0r/0s*). 2. After adding `((running+stopped)) &&`, I get `bash: ((: $(jobs -rp | wc -l): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$(jobs -rp | wc -l)")` as error when opening a new terminal.

Comment: Works for me: http://pastebin.com/vQtW9qJC . Have you noticed that I changed both the function (removed single quotes) and the `PS1` (changed double quotes to single ones)?

Comment: Your solution works correct if I start bash with `--norc` and paste the function online. The result is total different if I put that in my .bashrc file.

Comment: I tried it both directly from the command line and from my .bashrc. I had no issues. By the way, I put it at the very end of my .bashrc to make sure nothing alters the prompt after it. Do you have other `PS1` assignments there? If yes, post them so we can suggest a way to make all your prompt features compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're running this at every prompt, it's worth saving a few external calls.

To show the count only if there are background jobs, check the numbers and don't print anything if they're all 0.

Run `jobs -p` to get just the process IDs, it's easier to parse reliably.

```
jobscount() {
  set -- $(jobs -rp)
  set $# $(jobs -sp)
  set $1 $(($#-1))
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ] || [ $2 -ne 0 ]; then echo "${1}r/${2}s"; fi
}
PS1=' \w $(jobscount) \$ '
```

By the way, note the quotes around the right-hand side when assigning to `PS1`. With double quotes, the function is called when you set the variable. You need to use single quotes, so that the value of `PS1` contains the text `$(jobscount)` and the function is called each time the prompt is displayed.

You can save one fork by using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set a variable instead of using a function's output.

```
set_jobscount () {
  set $(jobs -rp)
  set $# $(jobs -sp)
  set $1 $(($#-1))
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ] || [ $2 -ne 0 ]; then
    jobscount="${1}r/${2}s"
  else
    jobscount=
  fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND
set_jobscount"
PS1=' \w ${jobscount} \$ '
```

---

As usual it's simpler (if cryptic-looking) in zsh.

```
precmd () {
  jobscount=${(M)#${jobstates%%:*}:#running}r/${(M)#${jobstates%%:*}:#suspended}s
  if [[ $jobscount == r0/s0 ]]; then jobscount=; fi
}
setopt prompt_subst
PS1='… ${jobscount} …'
```

Here [`jobstates`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-jobstates) is Zsh provided variable from [`zsh/parameter`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) module. `#running` and `#suspended` separates output to include only either running or suspended jobs. `(M)` flag and `%%` are from [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). `(M)` flag removes the non-matched elements and `%%` deletes anything after `:` from the output of `$jobstates`

Comment: `set $(jobs -rp)` produces the same verbose output as `set` if there are no running jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a variant of this to [show the exit code only if it's non-zero](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/6967a8b1523c8c2828c4c6ee23372a2320bb0d79/.bashrc#L64):

```
PS1=' \w $(running=$(jobscount); [ "${running:-0}" -eq 0 ] || printf %s "$running") \$ '
```

The code inside will run every time the prompt is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

how about $() in PS1, like:

```
export PS1='\w $(if test "\j" -ne "0"; then echo -e "\033[32m\j "; fi )\[\033[01;35m\]\$\[\033[00m\] '
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you could do:

```
PS1+='${_[\j<1]+[\j jobs] }'
```

`${_[n]}` is the `n`<sup>th</sup> element of the `$_` array. But that variable is not an array (or is an array with one element at index 0 as scalar variables are also known as in Korn-like shells).

So `${_[n]+text}` only expands to `text` if `n` is 0.

Here we use `\j<1` for `n` which means `n` is 0 only when there is at least one job.

To fix the `1 jobs` to `1 job`:

```
PS1+='${_[\j<1]+[\j job${_[\j<2]+s}] }'
```

The zsh equivalent, which doesn't have to resort to hacks as there's a ternary `%(X.text-for-true.text-for-false)` prompt expansion operator there:

```
PS1+='%(1j.[%j job%(2j.s.)] .)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following version doesn't run any external commands (AFAIK). Also, it treats the number of jobs atomically (with other solutions it may have changed before printing).

```bash
__jobs_ps1() { (( $1 )) && echo "[$1 jobs] "; }
PS1+='$(__jobs_ps1 \j)'
```

Comment: `[` aka `test` is builtin. Note that in any case, in bash `$(...)` always forks a process.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you're right about test being builtin, I always thought you had to use `[[` to avoid calling the external `test` command. I'll edit my answer. Do you think `$()` forks a process here, if we're only calling a function?

Comment: Yes, it forks a process as it collects the output through a pipe. See my answer (which I've just undeleted) for a version that doesn't fork.

Comment: Nice @StéphaneChazelas, very creative :-)